# Selenium параллельные тесты C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Всем привет!
Только что пришел на проект, возникла необходимость распараллелить автотесты UI,
Проект написан как консольное приложение C#, сами сценарии написаны на json (обычные блоки, в которых лежат переменные типа int, double, bool и т.п.)
Т.е. при запуске проекта в аргументы командной строки передаешь директорию, где лежит нужный сценарий, и как только ПО доходит до ключевых моментов заполнения web - страницы он смотрит на значения json и заполняет в соответствии с ними.
Есть 4 тестовых стэнда.
Сейчас более 100 тестов по 20 минут (длинные) и 100 по 5-10 минут, ПРИМЕРНО.
Что можно придумать, чтобы сократить время тестов, сейчас они прогоняются за 20 часов, банальный Sleep уже полностью посносил из проекта.
Фичи типа Selenoid или Selenium Grid тут не сработают, так как не смогут запустить тесты в разных потоках, потому что это КОНСОЛЬНОЕ приложение.
Что имею: виртуальную машину с 16 гб. RAM, TeamCity (2 АГЕНТА), стэк ELK, пожалуйста, помогите!
Пробовал сделать: создал 3 учетки Windows, на них клонировал проект, написал на одной из учеток bat-файл в него положил команду runas, все как бы круто они запускаются, но при заполнении чего либо они падают, видимо воруют друг у друга данные...

Comment: Не пробовал, но напрашивается очевидное решение: вынести тесты из консольного приложения в dll, запускать тесты этой dll в Selenium Grid Попробуйте сначала переделать приложение в отдельной ветке на отдельном проекте в TeamCity - если PoC устроит - можно будет на постоянку переделать архитектуру. Просто так подумать: ваша архитектура кривая, мешает работе Grid => не боимся поменять архитектуру на нормальную, не ищем костыли на ru so и не клепаем самопальные батники.

Comment: Тоже думал, над вашим предложением, но я думаю, столько времени мне не дадут, проект довольно большой и писался ГОД)), я даже и не знаю, что предпринять

Comment: Девять девушек не смогут родить за месяц. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Если задача реально сложная - то наивно думать, что один новый человек без опыта вдруг придёт и победит там, где год специалисты не справились. В такой ситуации будет непрофессионально с вашей стороны обещать больше, чем вы можете.

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо, что откликнулись, нужно будет искать тогда другие выходы